# cpp how to pass object of type state_t* to function

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to implement the gap heuristic in cpp. Here is the signature of my function:

```
get_gap_heuristic(state_t *state, string direction)
```

Here is a snippet of code within the function:

```
state_t goal_state;
    queue<state_t> goal_states = get_goal_states();
    int min_gap = -1;
    int gap;
    while (!goal_states.empty())
    {
        goal_state = goal_states.front();
        goal_states.pop();
        gap = get_gap(&state, goal_state);
```

where state is the method parameter as shown on the signature. 
When I try to execute my code, I get the following error:

```
a_star.cpp: In function ‘int get_gap_heuristic(state_t*, std::string)’:
a_star.cpp:73:41: error: cannot convert ‘state_t**’ to ‘state_t*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int get_gap(state_t*, state_t*)’
         gap = get_gap(&state, goal_state);
                                     ^
```

make: *** [Makefile:32: pancake.astar] Error 1

I've tried replacing goal_state with everything ie. :

> 1. just goal_state
> 2. &goal_state
> 3. *goal_state.

to no avail. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Your trying to fix the wrong argument. Fix `state` instead of `goal_state`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I would never have figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `state` is a pointer to `state_t`, 
In the below line:

```
gap = get_gap(&state, goal_state);
```

`&state` will **a pointer to pointer** to `state_t`.

And from the error message: 
The first parameter   of `get_gap` is a pointer to `state_t`.
So you have to call it like this:

```
gap = get_gap(state, goal_state);
```